# Integrating React App into ASP.NET Core Project: JSX File Not Rendering

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, jsx, visual-studio-2022

I've recently combined my React and ASP.NET Core projects into a single Visual Studio 2022 project template, transitioning from my initial setup of using VS Code for React and VS 2022 for ASP.NET Core. However, I encountered an issue when trying to integrate my existing React app. Specifically, when attempting to include a JSX file using the following code inside the .html head tag:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="./****/src/cart.jsx"></script>
```

I expected this to render the React component in my HTML. Instead, the JSX file doesn't display at all or have any signs of displaying, while if I directly navigate the page to the JSX file, the browser only shows the code as a text.

How can I correctly integrate my React JSX files into the ASP.NET Core project so they render properly in the browser?

[image: */cart.html]

UPDATE:

Solution found, need to add in the start of body this line:

```
    <script type="module" src="pathToJSXFile"></script>
```